# mvn release to push to git using a specific private key

Tags: git, maven, ssh

I hope someone can help with this. I'm trying to configure the `mvn release` plugin in `pom.xml` so that the updated pom version and tag are pushed to the git repo as part of `release:prepare`. Crucially, **it needs to use the ssh private key of a specific user**, as ultimately this will be part of our CI stack.

In the `pom.xml` I currently have a very simple config for the release plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- release plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
```

The `scm` settings in the pom look like this:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://ssh@bitbucket.org/**account**/**project**.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/**account**/**project**.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/**account**/**project**</url>
</scm>
```

And I have the following property in the pom (though not sure if this is used or not - I found reference to it on a loosely related problem):

```
<properties>
    <project.scm.id>bitbucket.org</project.scm.id>
```

Lastly, I have the following in mvn's `settings.xml` :

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>bitbucket.org</id>
        <privateKey>~/.ssh/bitbucket-read-write-access</privateKey>
        <passphrase></passphrase>
    </server>
```

The private key file `~/.ssh/bitbucket-read-write-access` exists, and there are no other keys in that folder (I have deliberately removed the default `id_rsa`)

When I run `mvn release:perform`, it fails when it tries to push to the repo:

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/nathanrussell/projects/**project** && git push ssh:********@bitbucket.org/**account**/**project**.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[INFO] Working directory: /home/nathanrussell/projects/**project**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.162 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-09T15:25:36Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project **project**: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
```

The only way I can get it to push correctly is to rename the file `~/.ssh/bitbucket-read-write-access` to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` which leads me to believe that:

- The user associated with the private key has the correct permissions on the repo and the public key is correctly associated with the repo user
- My configuration of the `pom.xml` and/or `settings.xml` is not quite right in respect of choosing/using the desired private key

(Before anyone suggests it, I cannot simply rename the key to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` because when we run this on the CI stack, it already has a default ssh key for another purpose)

Any thoughts or help with this would be very much appreciated

---

Some additional info:
If I do `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/bitbucket-read-write-access"` then `git push`, it pushes fine, which further leads me to believe the private/public key are correctly configured; and it's the mvn config that is wrong.

Comment: You declared a `<passphrase>` that's empty. Is that intentional? Are there further information when running `mvn ... -X`?

Comment: @GeroldBroser - I've tried it with the empty `<passphrase>`, a self-closing `<passphrase/>` and no element at all - all 3 options give the same result. Re: `mvn... -X`, yes, I've tried it, but nothing additional is logged in this respect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this working, I used a variant of the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` approach that I wrote about in the original question.

Whilst `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` worked on my development machine, the version of `git` on our CI stack is quite old  (1.7.1) and `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` is not supported! (`GIT_SSH_COMMAND` was introduced in 2.10)

I got this working with a combination of the `GIT_SSH` environment variable, and a shell script:

`export GIT_SSH=/var/home/teamcity/.ssh/ssh-using-bitbucket-read-write-access.sh`

and

```
$ cat /var/home/teamcity/.ssh/ssh-using-bitbucket-read-write-access.sh
#!/bin/bash

ssh -i ~/.ssh/bitbucket-read-write-access $*
```

It feels a bit of a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

There's a cleaner solution; just use

```sh
ssh-add ~/.ssh/path-to-key
```